# hidde all rows with value n/d vba excel microsoft

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, rows, hidden

if you push the green button, All rows with a value in the column Loc #N/d will be hidden

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see column names in your screenshot, so the below example assumes Loc is column D.

In your code that executes when clicking the green button, add this line to hide all cells with errors:

```
Range("D:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Comment: as the range A: I remove spaces from all cells through VBA?

Comment: @Grz3siu did my answer solve your original question? If so, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @Grz3siu For the removal of spaces, look into using the .Replace method. I'm on my phone so I can't post code now but I can look into it tomorrow.

Comment: Your answer solves the problem :) done

Comment: @Grz3siu For the space removal, try `Range("A:I").Replace(" ", vbNullString)`